# Uploading a user-provided image and storing it safely

Tags: php, image-processing, amazon-s3, mime-types

In different parts of my application, I allow users to upload an image file  (which will be stored in AWS S3) to be displayed later on the site. Typically, profile pictures and logos.

My concerns are:

- Security. Is it really an image file? Is the user trying to upload a malicious file?
- Quality.
- File types. Some images are better as JPEG, some are better as PNG. The uploader probably knows best since it is his file.
- File extensions. I assume that browsers like it when the extension matches the file type. Hiding a PNG inside a ".jpg" is probably a bad idea?

The way I am currently doing it, I assume all images are meant to be JPEG. Then in PHP I am doing something like `imagejpeg(imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($from)), $tmp)`, which forces it to be a JPEG file. I then upload the generated file to S3 as `image/jpeg`. The name is generated automatically and always ends with ".jpg".

I believe this takes care of "security" as the file is re-generated as a JPEG (but maybe I'm wrong?). But it definitely doesn't handle cases where the user wanted to upload a PNG file.

Tips?

(using PHP, Yii, AWS)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at the "magic numbers" of the file being uploaded as per this link I found http://x10hosting.com/forums/tutorials/106510-securing-your-php-file-upload-scripts.html this is a lot safer as you are not relying on a file extension, you would need to craete a whitelist of the files you want to allow and just boot the remainders.

It would make more sense converting the uploaded images to the correct format rather than hiding them within another file extension, masking the original extension might work on most browsers, but you are bound to run into issues down the line. I would reccomend making use of either imagemagick for this.

Finally - you might want to look into PHPs `move_uploaded_file` function to ensure that the uploaded file is valid `http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php`.

Hope this helps!